# How flutter create expand text

Tags: flutter

How to do this function shown as below images?

**Unexpanded text:**

[image: Unexpanded text]

**Expanded text:**

[image: Expanded text]

```
final List<String> items = [
  'Item1',
  'Item2',
  'Item3',
  'Item4',
];
String? selectedValue;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton2<String>(
          isExpanded: true,
          hint: Text(
            'Select Item',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
              color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
            ),
          ),
          items: items
              .map((String item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: item,
                    child: Text(
                      item,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList(),
          value: selectedValue,
          onChanged: (String? value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValue = value;
            });
          },
          buttonStyleData: const ButtonStyleData(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            height: 40,
            width: 140,
          ),
          menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(
            height: 40,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image: images]

Above coding that's not my expectation.

Comment: [Don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557), and provide more details.

Comment: https://blog.logrocket.com/expansionpanel-flutter-guide-with-examples/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through `ExpansionTile` class, read more about it on [Flutter's documentation website](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html).

This is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [ExpansionTile].

void main() => runApp(const ExpansionTileApp());

class ExpansionTileApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExpansionTileApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('ExpansionTile Sample')),
        body: const ExpansionTileExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExpansionTileExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpansionTileExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExpansionTileExample> createState() => _ExpansionTileExampleState();
}

class _ExpansionTileExampleState extends State<ExpansionTileExample> {
  bool _customTileExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        const ExpansionTile(
          title: Text('ExpansionTile 1'),
          subtitle: Text('Trailing expansion arrow icon'),
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 1')),
          ],
        ),
        ExpansionTile(
          title: const Text('ExpansionTile 2'),
          subtitle: const Text('Custom expansion arrow icon'),
          trailing: Icon(
            _customTileExpanded
                ? Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle
                : Icons.arrow_drop_down,
          ),
          children: const <Widget>[
            ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 2')),
          ],
          onExpansionChanged: (bool expanded) {
            setState(() {
              _customTileExpanded = expanded;
            });
          },
        ),
        const ExpansionTile(
          title: Text('ExpansionTile 3'),
          subtitle: Text('Leading expansion arrow icon'),
          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 3')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```